# Android как убрать дублирование в таблице очков?

Tags: android, textview

Всем привет, я делаю мини-викторину в своем приложении и вот столькнулся с проблемой. Смотрите, игрок №1 получает 1000 очков его данные записываются в textview на лучшее место, игрок №2 тоже получает 1000 очков и его данные тоже записываются в таблицу, но уже со смещением.

Я хочу чтобы одинаковые результаты перезаписывались, а не смещались как у меня на скриншоте.

Заранее спасибо всем, кто откликнулся в помощи :)

(В android studio я считай новичок поэтому не судите строго за код и за незнания чего либо)

Вот скрин:

[image]

Вот код таблицы очков:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
    lastScrol = preferences.getInt("lastScrol", 0);
    best1 = preferences.getInt("best1", 0);
    best2 = preferences.getInt("best2", 0);
    best3 = preferences.getInt("best3", 0);

    name = preferences.getString("UserName","");
    name1 = preferences.getString("UserName1","");
    name2 = preferences.getString("UserName2","");
    name3 = preferences.getString("UserName3","");

    //name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");






    if (lastScrol > best3 || lastScrol < best3){
        best3 = lastScrol;
        name3 = name;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("best3", best3);
        editor.putString("UserName3",name3);
        editor.apply();
    }

    if (lastScrol > best2){
        int temp = best2;
        String tempName = name2;
        best2 = lastScrol;
        name2 = name;
        best3 = temp;
        name3 = tempName;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("best3", best3);
        editor.putString("UserName3",name3);
        editor.putInt("best2", best2);
        editor.putString("UserName2",name2);
        editor.apply();
    }

    if (lastScrol > best1){
        int temp = best1;
        String tempName = name1;
        best1 = lastScrol;
        name1 = name;
        best2 = temp;
        name2 = tempName;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("best2", best2);
        editor.putString("UserName2",name2);
        editor.putInt("best1", best1);
        editor.putString("UserName1",name1);
        editor.apply();
    }





    scrol.setText("Последний результат:  " + name + " " + lastScrol + " очков" +" \n" +
    "Лучший результат:  " + name1  + " " + best1 + " \n" +
            "Средний результат:  " + name2 + " " + best2 + " \n" +
            "Худший результат:  "+ name3 + " " + best3 + " \n");
```

Comment: Объясни понятно, что хочешь, ничего не понятно.  Рисунок нарисуй.

Comment: вроде бы понятно все обьяснил...
Когда я получаю одинаковое количество очков, то хочу чтобы они не дублировались, а просто не записывались в таблицу. 
А У МЕНЯ ЗАПИСЫВАЮТСЯ.
Например: Я прошел квест и заработал 800 очков, мой результат переместился в поле "Лучший результат". Потом я еще раз прохожу квест и опят таки зарабатываю 800 очков и эти самые очки должны перезаписываться в поле "Лучший результат", а не перемещаться дальше как это показано у меня на скрине. Надеюсь теперь понятно обьяснил))

Comment: Нет, непонятно. На скрине четыре РАЗНЫХ результата (лучший, средний, последний и худший). Какой из них куда перемещается?

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста код самой таблицы очков.

Comment: чем может помочь код? Он делает именно то, что в нем написано.

Comment: Вам может проблема и кажется очевидной, но человеку, который видит все это со стороны совершенно ничего не понятно, попытайтесь донести свою проблему так, чтобы сало ясно, в чем именно она состоит. Я вот тоже ничего не понял о вашей проблеме и не вижу что тут может куда смещаться. Есть четыре результата, в них четыре значения, что с ними не так и как должно быть правильно. Смотреть ваш код, к сожалению, тяжелое испытание, осилить его логику еще сложнее, чем то, что написано словами.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял, сори, сейчас попытаюсь донести свою проблему максимально понятно))
Захожу в игру. Таблица не заполнена еще. Ввожу своё имя допустим "Егор", допустим набрал 800 очков. Эти данные записались в таблицу "Лучший результат" и в "Послед результат". Потом играю в игру еще раз под именем "Яна", набираю 1000 очков. Эти данные  Записываются в таблицу "Послед результат" и  "лучший результат" т.к.  У "Яна" набрала больше очков чем "Саша". Данные "Саши" смещаются в таблицу "Средний результат".

Comment: И вот я уже играю под именем "Дима", она набирает 900 очков. Его данные записались в таблицу "последний результат" и в таблицу "средний результат" т.к. он набрал больше очков чем "Яна". Данные "Яны" сместились в таблицу "худший результат".  С помощью if проверяем число если оно больше чем в "лучшем результате", то записываем туда данные, а предыдущие данные "лучшего результата" смещаются вниз с помощью temp и записываются в "средний результат",а данные "среднего результат" смещаются вниз и записываются в "худший результат".

Comment: САМА ПРОБЛЕМА
Таблица заполнена так:
Лучший результат Яна 1000 очков
Средний результат: Дима 900 очков
Худший результат: Егор 800 очков

И вот играю уже под именем "Серж" он тоже набрал 1000 очко как и "Яна".
Таблица выглядит вот так:

Лучший результат Серж 1000 очков
Средний результат: Яна 1000 очков
Худший результат: Дима 900 очков

Я  хочу чтобы просто данные "Сержа" перезаписались на место Яны и не было никаких смещений. Таблица должна выглядить вот так
Лучший результат Серж 1000 очков
Средний результат: Дима 900 очков
Худший результат: Егор 800 очков

Comment: Ну теперь вроде что то понятно. Если результат одинаковый с прошлым лучшим, то просто заменять его? Я думаю, что строка "средний результат" совершенно лишняя, способ ее вычисления не очевиден, а смысл бесполезен . Только писать уточнения к вопросу надо не в комментарии под ним, а правкой самого вопроса (кнопка "править" под вопросом)